# C# Serial Port gives unwanted IRP messages

Tags: c#, rfid, hid, custom-keyboard

I am trying to send commands to and RFID reader through a serial port (it acts like a keyboard, M302 made by KKMOON).

I have this piece of code in order to send instructions:

```
SerialPort sp = new SerialPort();
sp.PortName = "COM3";
sp.BaudRate = 9600;
sp.Parity = Parity.None;
sp.DataBits = 8;
sp.StopBits = StopBits.One;

sp.DataReceived += myRecieved;

sp.Open();
byte[] bytestosend = { 0x03, 0x0a, 0x00, 0x0d };
sp.Write(bytestosend, 0, bytestosend.Length);

bytestosend = new byte[]{ 0x04, 0x05, 0x00, 0x00, 0x09 };
sp.Write(bytestosend, 0, bytestosend.Length);

bytestosend = new byte[] { 0x03, 0x06, 0x00, 0x09 };
sp.Write(bytestosend, 0, bytestosend.Length);

if (beep)
{
    running = false;
    bytestosend = new byte[] { 0x02, 0x13, 0x15 };
    sp.Write(bytestosend, 0, bytestosend.Length);
}

sp.Close();
sp.Dispose();
sp = null;
```

and I'm getting this output from a serial port listener:
[image: The Current Output from the Serial Program]

The output that I need to get in order to read the data is
[image: The required data]

Comment: You're totally out of luck using the Microsoft SerialPort class.  It *will* generate GetCommStatus and WaitCommEvent calls.  To avoid them, call the Win32 Communications Port API directly

Comment: You are focusing on the wrong problem.  The code in the snippet takes, maybe, a microsecond.  Getting data from the device takes much longer, serial ports are not that fast.  If you are going to use DataReceived then you must *not* call Close().  If you need a response to each Write() then don't use the DataReceived event, use Read().  You must always avoid a scenario where you repeatedly call Open and Close, the MSDN article for Close specifically warns about that.

Comment: @HansPassant thank you for that! Just used a timed query in order to read after data has been sent!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after Hans Passant's comment I realised that the problem was actually just not reading the serial port correctly!

In order to read the full extent of the message I built a method that reads the entire buffer:

```
private static string readData()
{
    int reads = sp.BytesToRead;

    byte[] bytesRead = new byte[reads];

    try
    {
        sp.Read(bytesRead, 0, reads);

        return BitConverter.ToString(bytesRead).Trim(' ') != "" ? BitConverter.ToString(bytesRead) : "-1";
    }
    catch
    {
        return "-1";
    }
}
```

and then read the entire buffer until the wanted return data is found

```
while ((data += readData()) != "02-05-07")
{
    if (data.Contains("-1"))
    {
        data = "";
    }
    Console.WriteLine(data);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

This will allow me to read all the data from my RFID reader and I hope this helps anyone else who might have a problem!